# Twitter4j - Search tweets using multiple query terms with the "and" operator not working

Tags: java, twitter4j

I'm trying to retrieve tweets for a given set of search terms using twitter4j.

I can successfully retrieve tweets for a query with only one term, or a query using the OR operator, but when I enter an AND condition in the query I get zero results. I have completed the same query [on Twitter's search bar](http://twitter.com/search) and I get hundreds of results.

It looks like [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24953833/twitter4j-search-query-not-working) references a similar issue, but there is no listed solution.

I would like to get results for the query "#treet java"

Here's my method that completes the search...

```
// queryString = "#treet" - works
// queryString = "java" - works
// queryString = "#treet OR java" - works
// queryString = "#treet java" - doesn't work
// queryString = "#treet AND java" - doesn't work

public static Treet[] loadAndSaveRemote() {
        Twitter twitter = TwitterFactory.getSingleton();
        Query query = new Query();
        query.setQuery(queryString);
        query.setCount(100);
        QueryResult result = null;

        try {
            result = twitter.search(query);
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            System.out.println("Getting tweet failed");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        List<Status> tweets = result.getTweets();
        List<Treet> list = new ArrayList<>();

        // With queries using "term1 term2" the output is "0 tweets were retrieved" in all cases
        System.out.printf("%d tweets were retrieved %n", tweets.size());

        for (Status status : tweets) {
            list.add( new Treet(status.getUser().getScreenName(),
                                      status.getText(),
                                      status.getCreatedAt()));
        }
        Treet[] returning = list.toArray(new Treet[list.size()]);
        Treets.save(returning);
        return returning;
    }
```

I have looked at the [Twitter search api](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search) and my query syntax seems correct. I have also seen examples online using a similar format.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.